# : first path segment in URL cannot contain colon

Tags: go

Here's my code ( part of it ) :

```
type SitemapIndex struct {
    // Locations []Location `xml:"sitemap"`
    Locations []string `xml:"sitemap>loc"`
}

~~~ SNIP ~~~
func main(){
    var s SitemapIndex
    resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml")
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)
    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", Location)
        resp, err := http.Get(Location)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } else {
            bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &n)
            for idx := range n.Titles {
                newsMap[n.Titles[idx]] = NewsMap{n.Keywords[idx], n.Locations[idx]}
            }
        }
        for idx, data := range newsMap {
            fmt.Println("\n\n\n", idx)
            fmt.Println("\n", data.Keyword)
            fmt.Println("\n", data.Location)
        }
    }
```

Now, when I run this code I get this output :

```
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml

2019/01/28 02:37:13 parse 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml
: first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
exit status 1
```

I read a few posts and did some experiment myself, like I made another file with the following code

```
package main

import ("fmt"
    "net/url")

func main(){
    fmt.Println(url.Parse("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml"))
}
```

And it didn't throw any error, so I understand the error is not with the url .

Now, I just started learning **Go** using sentdex's tutorials , a few hours ago and so don't have much idea as of now. Here's the [video link](https://youtu.be/2umnbZxdu-s?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX&t=485)

Thanks and regards.
Temporarya

Comment: I had this same error and it was because there was `GET` in the url string. E.g. `"GET https://management.azure.com/%s/maps?api-version=2016-06-01"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that `Location` has whitespace prefix and suffix so string is not valid URL. Unfortunately, error message does not help to see that.

**How to detect:**

I typically use %q `fmt` helper that wraps string into parentheses:

```
fmt.Printf("%q", Location)
```

Will be printed as "\nhttps://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/politics.xml\n"

**How to fix:**

add this line before using Location in code:

```
Location = strings.TrimSpace(Location)
```

Answer (score 11):

Another reason to get this error is when you use an IP address without specifying the protocol before it.

Example for cases you'll get this error:

```
parsedUrl, err := url.Parse("127.0.0.1:3213")
```

How to fix it:

```
parsedUrl, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:3213")
```

Poor documentation, unfortunately.

Comment: Worked for me. I just added the http:// part and error went away.

Comment: hahahaha , thanks for saving me ! one of the worst thing happen to me today

Comment: curl, for example. handles both `"127.0.0.1:3213"` and `"http://127.0.0.1:3213"`. Why can't we have func which does the same in go?

Comment: @quant2016 http is the default curl protocol, so curl is in in fact generating the `http://127.0.0.1:3213` string. Detecting a protocol is not defined in a lot of cases, `ws://127.0.0.1`, `http://127.0.0.1` and `https://127.0.0.1` all share the same origin but correspond to wildly different servers.

Comment: @qciccoretti it would be nice to treat "127.0.0.1:1234" the same way as "//127.0.0.1". It's easier to replace empty scheme with appropriate default in my code than to tell everybody that they have to always write protocol in args or configs.

Comment: I even created my own fixed version for that: https://pastebin.com/2SpHTwWC and I'm not sure if it always works correctly